# Is there an iframe attack surface to webcache.googleusercontent.com?

Tags: google, same-origin-policy, iframe

I've noticed that one of my web-sites shows up pretty much blank when viewed from Google Cache at `webcache.googleusercontent.com`, because Google apparently must be inserting the following extra header, which, apparently, makes SeaMonkey not display whichever content is supplied through an **`iframe`** (which I'm using as the HTML5 equivalent of the deprecated **`frameset`**):

> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

What's exactly the attack surface here?  Isn't Google Cache already supposed to include user content?

Has it just been included without much thought, or is there a genuine attack surface here?